# Select date as YYYYMMDD Format in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm able to query date format as YYYY-MM-DD with the following commands:

```
select date(now());
select date(now()) - INTERVAL N DAY;
```

Is there any other way that I can select date as YYYYMMDD format in sql?

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax looks like MySQL.  You can convert the value to a string explicitly:

```
select date_format(now(), '%Y%m%d')
```